# how to ssh to hostname without giving fqdn

Tags: command-line, scripts, ssh

currently i am working on lots of server which are having very lengthy fqdn.
example prodService.xyz.pdr.abc.com and i want to do ssh to server like below without giving fqdn ,it should take fqdn from server itself, this feature needs to be available for all users on that box so it should be done on os leve.

```
ssh prodService -like this 
ssh prodService.xyz.pdr.abc.com - not like this.
```

FYI: my jumpbox linux box is in diff fdqn hence need to give completed fqdn every time)
Any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Add entries to `~/.ssh/config` (for a specific user) or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (for all users) as

```
Host prodService
    Hostname prodService.xyz.pdr.abc.com
    ... other options for this host...
```